# Data not completely migrated using SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package using BIDS 2008 which is for SQL Server 2008 R2. I have created a Datflow task that contains oledb source and destination. Source contains executing the stored procedure and destination contains the name of the destination table

When I execute the stored procedure by itself, it returns 3723308, but when I check the destination table after executing the SSIS package, I see only 1861654.

Where has the rest of the data gone?

Please see the screenshot

Dataflow

[image]

Source

[image]

Conversion

[image]

Destination

[image]

Stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getPartiesMarketData_SSIS1]
    (@periodtypeId INT = 4)
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @date DATE = '2015-01-01'

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('maxPeriod') AND NAME ='idx_maxPeriod')
    DROP INDEX idx_maxPeriod ON maxPeriod

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('futurePer') AND NAME ='idx_futurePer')
    DROP INDEX idx_futurePer ON futurePer

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('PeriodTbl') AND NAME ='idx_PeriodTbl')
    DROP INDEX idx_PeriodTbl ON PeriodTbl

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('MarketTable') AND NAME ='idx_MarketTable')
    DROP INDEX idx_MarketTable ON MarketTable

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('PricingTable') AND NAME ='idx_PricingTable')
    DROP INDEX idx_PricingTable ON PricingTable

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE object_id = object_id('CompanyInfoTable') AND NAME ='idx_CompanyInfoTable')
    DROP INDEX idx_CompanyInfoTable ON CompanyInfoTable



INSERT INTO maxPeriod  
select 
        fp.companyId,
        max(fi.periodenddate) as maxPeriod

from ciqfinperiod fp inner join ciqcompany ci on fp.companyId = ci.companyId
        join ciqfininstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
where fp.periodtypeid = 4
        and fi.periodenddate > @date
        and fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag = 1
        and latestfilingforinstanceflag = 1 

group by fp.companyId

create nonclustered index idx_maxPeriod on [dbo].[maxPeriod](companyId,maxPeriod)


INSERT INTO futurePer       
select 
        a.companyId,
        adjFQ = case when a.fiscalQuarter = 4 then 1 else a.fiscalQuarter + 1 end, 
        adjFY = case when a.fiscalQuarter = 4 then a.fiscalYear + 1 else a.fiscalYear end

from(
        select 
            fp.companyId, 
            fp.fiscalYear,
            fp.fiscalQuarter,
            row_number() over (partition by fp.companyId order by fp.fiscalYear desc, fp.fiscalQuarter desc) as rowno

        from ciqfinperiod fp inner join ciqcompany ci on fp.companyId = ci.companyId

) a 
where a.rowno = 1

create nonclustered index idx_futurePer on [dbo].[futurePer](companyId)       

INSERT INTO PeriodTbl              
select 
        companyId,
        fiscalYear,
        fiscalQuarter,
        periodenddate

from( 
        select
            fp.companyId,
            fp.fiscalYear,
            fp.fiscalQuarter,
            fi.periodenddate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fp.companyId, fp.fiscalYear, fp.fiscalQuarter ORDER BY fi.periodEndDate DESC) rowno
        from ciqfinperiod fp inner join ciqcompany ci on fp.companyId = ci.companyId
            join ciqfininstance fi on fi.financialperiodid = fp.financialperiodid
        where fp.periodtypeid = 4
            and fi.periodenddate > @date
            and fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag = 1
            and latestfilingforinstanceflag = 1 


        ) a
where a.rowno = 1

 create nonclustered index idx_PeriodTbl on [dbo].[PeriodTbl](companyId,fiscalYear,fiscalQuarter,periodenddate)      

INSERT INTO MarketTable        
select 
        mc.companyId,
        mc.pricingDate,
        mc.tev,
        mc.sharesOutstanding,
        mc.marketCap 

from ciqMarketCap mc inner join ciqcompany ci on mc.companyId = ci.companyId
where mc.pricingDate > @date

create nonclustered index idx_MarketTable on [dbo].[MarketTable](companyId,pricingDate)      

INSERT INTO PricingTable   
select
        s.companyId,
        peq.pricingDate,
        ti.currencyId, 
        peq.priceMid

from ciqsecurity s inner join ciqcompany ci on s.companyId = ci.companyId
        join ciqtradingitem ti on s.securityid = ti.securityid
        join ciqpriceequity peq on peq.tradingitemid = ti.tradingitemid
where s.primaryFlag = 1
        --and s.companyId in (select id from #companyId)
        and peq.pricingDate> @date
        and ti.primaryflag = 1

create nonclustered index idx_PricingTable on [dbo].[PricingTable](companyId,pricingDate)


INSERT INTO CompanyInfoTable
select
        s.companyId,
        ti.currencyId,
        ti.tickerSymbol,
        e.exchangeName

from ciqSecurity s inner join ciqcompany  cit on s.companyId = cit.companyId
        join ciqTradingItem ti on ti.securityId = s.securityId
        join ciqExchange e on e.exchangeId = ti.exchangeId
where
        ti.primaryFlag = 1
        and s.primaryFlag = 1
        --and s.companyid in (select id from #companyId)

create nonclustered index idx_CompanyInfoTable on [dbo].[CompanyInfoTable](companyId)       
--/* produce a table that includes the companyid, periodenddate, pricingdate,
--and currencypricingdate for look ups*/

/* determine the differences between the dates*/
;with histTbl_CTE 
as (
        select 
            a.companyid,
            a.periodenddate,
            a.pricingdate,
            fp.fiscalYear,
            fp.fiscalQuarter,
            pt.periodtypeId
        from (
            /* determine the cartesian product of periodenddate and pricingdate, assigning 
            a periodenddate to every pricing date that is less than the periodenddate */
                    select 
                            per.companyid, 
                            periodenddate, 
                            pric.pricingdate,
                            datediff(day, pricingdate, periodenddate) as peqdiffdate
                    from  PeriodTbl per
                    join PricingTable pric
                    on (per.companyid = pric.companyid 
                            and per.periodenddate >= pric.pricingdate)
            ) a
        inner join (
                    /*find the different between the pricing date and the period end date */
                    select 
                            per.companyid,
                            periodenddate,
                            min(datediff(day, pricingdate, periodenddate)) minpeqdiffdate
                    from 
                    PeriodTbl per
                    join PricingTable pric
                    on (per.companyid = pric.companyid
                            and per.periodenddate >= pric.pricingdate)
                    group by per.companyid, per.fiscalyear, per.fiscalquarter, periodenddate
            )b
        on a.companyid = b.companyid 
            and a.periodenddate = b.periodenddate
            and a.peqdiffdate = b.minpeqdiffdate
        left join ciqFinPeriod fp on a.companyId = fp.companyId
        left join ciqFinInstance fi on (a.periodenddate = fi.periodenddate
                                                    and fi.financialPeriodId = fp.financialPeriodId)
        left join ciqPeriodType pt on pt.periodTypeId = fp.periodTypeId
        where fi.latestforfinancialperiodflag = 1
            and latestfilingforinstanceflag = 1
            and pt.periodtypeid = 4
        group by a.companyid, a.periodenddate, a.pricingdate, fp.fiscalYear, fp.fiscalQuarter, pt.periodtypeid
        ), 
recentTbl_CTE 
        as (
        --/* use the same methodology from above to find the most recent dates */
        select 
            temp.companyId,
            max(periodenddate) as periodenddate,
            max(peqdate) as pricingDate,
            x.adjFY as fiscalYear,
            x.adjFQ as fiscalQuarter,
            periodTypeId = NULL
        from(
            select
                    a.companyId,
                    a.periodenddate,
                    a.peqdate,
                    b.minpeqdiffdate
            from(
                    select 
                            mc.companyId,
                            mc.pricingDate as periodenddate,
                            peq.pricingDate as peqdate,
                            datediff(day, peq.pricingDate, mc.pricingDate) as peqdiffdate
                    from MarketTable mc
                    join PricingTable peq
                    on  (mc.companyId = peq.companyId
                            and mc.pricingDate >=peq.pricingDate)
                    group by mc.companyid, mc.pricingDate, peq.pricingDate
                    ) a
            inner join (
                    select 
                            mc.companyId,
                            mc.pricingdate as periodenddate,
                            min(datediff(day, peq.pricingDate, mc.pricingDate)) as minpeqdiffdate
                    from MarketTable mc
                    join PricingTable peq 
                    on (mc.companyId = peq.companyId
                            and mc.pricingDate >= peq.pricingDate)
                    group by mc.companyid, mc.pricingDate
                    ) b on 
                            a.companyId = b.companyId
                            and a.periodenddate = b.periodenddate
                            and a.peqdiffdate = b.minpeqdiffdate
                    ) temp
        join futurePer x on x.companyId = temp.companyId
        group by temp.companyid, minpeqdiffdate, adjFY, adjFQ
        having minpeqdiffdate = 0
        )


/* combine all table and join the data*/
select
        combined.companyId,
        combined.periodEndDate,
        combined.dataItemName,
        case when combined.dataItemName = 'priceMidUSD' then combined.dataItemvalue/exR.currencyRateClose * 1
            when combined.dataItemName = 'sharesOutstanding' then combined.dataItemvalue
            when combined.dataItemName = 'marketcaptrend' then combined.dataItemvalue
            else combined.dataItemvalue/exR.currencyRateClose * 1e6 end as dataItemvalue,
        combined.fiscalYear,
        combined.fiscalQuarter,
        combined.periodTypeId,
        ctbl.tickerSymbol,
        ctbl.exchangeName,
        id.dataItemId
from(
        select
            companyId,
            pricingdate,
            periodenddate,
            currencyId,
            dataItemName,
            cast(dataItemidue as float) as dataItemvalue,
            fiscalYear,
            fiscalQuarter,
            periodTypeId
        from(
            select 
                            a.companyId,
                            a.pricingdate,
                            c.currencyId, 
                            a.periodenddate,
                            cast(c.priceMid as nvarchar(100)) as priceMidUSD,
                            cast(d.marketCap as nvarchar(100)) as marketCapUSD,
                            cast((d.marketCap/nullif(prevmc.prevmarketCap,0)) - 1 as nvarchar(100)) as marketcaptrend,
                            cast(d.TEV as nvarchar(100)) as TEV,
                            cast(d.sharesOutstanding as nvarchar(100)) as sharesOutstanding,
                            a.fiscalYear,
                            a.fiscalQuarter,
                            a.periodTypeId
            from (
                    select       
                            companyid,
                            periodenddate,
                            pricingdate,
                            fiscalYear,
                            fiscalQuarter,
                            periodtypeId 
                    from histTbl_CTE

                    union all

                    select
                            companyId,
                            periodenddate,
                            pricingDate,
                            fiscalYear,
                            fiscalQuarter,
                            periodTypeId
                    from recentTbl_CTE
                            )a
            join PricingTable c
                    on (
                    c.pricingdate = a.pricingDate
                    and c.companyId = a.companyId )
            join MarketTable d
                    on (
                    d.companyId = a.companyId
                    and d.pricingDate = a.periodenddate)
            left join (
                    select a.companyId,
                            a.pricingDate,
                            a.prevperiod, 
                            b.marketcap as prevmarketcap
                    from(
                            select 
                                mc.companyid,
                                mc.pricingdate,
                                mc.pricingdate -365 as 'prevperiod'
                            from
                                ciqMarketCap mc
                                join ciqCompany c
                                    on c.companyId=mc.companyId
                            ) a
                    inner join (
                            select 
                                mc.companyId,
                                mc.pricingdate,
                                mc.marketcap
                            from MarketTable mc 
                            ) b
                            on (a.companyid = b.companyid
                            and a.prevperiod = b.pricingdate)
            ) prevmc
                    on (prevmc.companyid = d.companyid
                            and prevmc.pricingdate = d.pricingdate)

            group by a.companyid, a.periodenddate, a.pricingDate, a.fiscalYear, a.fiscalQuarter, a.periodtypeid, c.currencyId,
                            c.pricemid, d.marketCap, d.TEV, d.sharesOutstanding, prevmc.prevperiod, prevmc.prevmarketcap
            ) c
                    unpivot
                    (dataItemidue for dataItemName in
                            (TEV, marketCapUSD, sharesOutstanding, marketcaptrend, priceMidUSD)
                            ) as unpvt
        ) combined 
join CompanyInfoTable ctbl on ctbl.companyId = combined.companyId
join CustomDataItem id on id.name = combined.dataitemname 
join ciqExchangeRate exR on (exR.currencyId = combined.currencyId and
                                                exR.pricingDate = combined.pricingDate)
order by combined.companyId,combined.fiscalYear desc,combined.fiscalQuarter desc

end
```

Result

[image]

Query Analyser results:

[image]

Comment: Could you provide us with your SP code? Do you have only 1 `SELECT` statement in your SP?

Comment: I am not in front of my PC but the sp is huge one. It contains lot many joins , sub queries as well use of CTE etc. What I can remember is the query starts with No Count On

Comment: my first guess is there are more than one `SELECT` that returning you the results, and the later one overwrites the former one

Comment: How is it that while executing the stored procedure it returns all the records but when run via SSIS it doesn't

Comment: could you paste a screenshot later for the finished execution window? that will have number of rows besides those transformations

Comment: 1861654 * 2 = 3723308.  So **exactly half** of the records are missing?   Your SP probably has multiple result sets.  SSIS will only read one.

Comment: How do I fix this

Comment: What period type are you passing in? Also @LONG's question is a good one: if you show a screenshot of the data flow after having run the package in BIDS in debug mode, it will show the number of rows flowing through each step, helping us identify where the problem is.

Comment: Sure I shall do that and post

Comment: I have updated the post as you can see the source and destination is the same. I did notice that the periodTypeId was having a value of 1 in SSIS but the correct value should have been 4. I did remove the parameter and execute thinking that would be the issue but again I get back the same records.

Comment: Can you post what you are seeing that makes you think the procedure returns 3.7M rows when you run it in SSMS?

Comment: Update post. When I run the query in Query Analyser it returns 3 millions above

Comment: Mysterious issue. Not sure what is happening

Comment: When you run the procedure in SSMS, according to your screenshot, you are not providing a parameter.   What happens if you take the parameter out in SSIS?   Also double check both are running on the same environment, and not one hitting DEV and the other hitting Stage or Production.

Comment: Issue resolved. The storedprocesdure was using physical tables for temporary purpose which the SSIS was truncating before it executed the proc. While executing the proc, the temp tables were populated with the initial SSIS run. So addign the truncate statements at the end of the storedproc fixed the issue.